# C# Windows Form Unit Testing

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, unit-testing

I'm writting unit test for the first time for existing software, and my boss has asked me to write a unit test outline/plan.

Being a very junior C# developer, I'm trying to find a way to create a test plan for this app.

I've set up an excel document, with multiple sheets representing each project in my solutions.
I'm confused on how document for all possible outcome and inputs, especially when working with void and bool methods. Or when passing models into a method, where there are many values being passed in.

How can I document pass,fail, expected results for the following 2 method, a basic outline is all I am looking for, not specific documentation:

```
public static void ManualEntryToggleStateChanged(bool isChecked)
        {
            /* check for manual entry
             * if manual entry information can be entered
             * focus user to reg no
             */
            moTextboxRegName.ReadOnly = !isChecked;

            moTextboxRegHerd.ReadOnly = !isChecked;

            if (isChecked)
            {
                moTextboxRegHerd.Text = "";
                moTextboxRegName.Text = "";
                moDropDownListBreed.Focus();
            }

        }
  public static void LoadAllLabs(nsHacBusSrv.SortMode Sort = nsHacBusSrv.SortMode.NotSorted)
    {
        try
        {
            moDropDownListLab.DataSource
                = moBusinessServices.GetAllLabs(Sort);

            moDropDownListLab.DisplayMember = "Name";

            moDropDownListLab.ValueMember = "Idn";

            nsTelWinUi.RadListDataItem oDefaultItem
                = new nsTelWinUi.RadListDataItem("", "");

            moDropDownListLab.Items.Add(oDefaultItem);

            moDropDownListLab.SelectedValue = "";
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(ex.Message);

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You more likely to succeed with the task if you ask around for sample of similar document/work...

Comment: Aliasing namespaces like that is a funny convention. Never seen that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use Excel?  If I were you I would add a test project to the solution.  The go to each solution and add unit tests for each of the methods.  If you have the right plug-ins for visual studio it will create all of the test case stubs for you.

As far as how to test, it's party art, but mostly science.  It all revovles around these things.  "Any given parameter is exhaustively tested if the following conditions are tested.. Min, Min-1, Min+1, Max, Max-1, Max+1.. There are two other special cases you have to consider when seeing them string.empty and null.  This gives you just 8 permutations to exhaustively test everything, but you'll find that most of the time you can reduce this number of tests based on what you are testing.  For example a bool value only has 2 permutations.  But a string parm has at least 7 permuations.

The art portion of test revolves around spotting patterns and determining how many perumatation are really needed.  For example two string parameters would take 7!-1 permutations to test all possibilities. 46 different tests, to get all states, but, if you look at the code closely enough often you can vastly reduce these numbers too.

The key to good testing is don't leave any stone unturned and assume nothing.  Let the tests tell you how robust the code is and not the developer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this answer, I found this very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a test where you assert the specified properties on the moTextboxRegName and moDropDownListLab objects. This assumes you have a way to expose those objects through your api though. When doing unit testing you have to write your code with the tests in mind in order to be able to test your code.